# VS Code Multi-Cursor Select to Brackets functionality

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext3, brackets

Is it possible to select multi cursor select to brackets altogether via single action?

e.g.

```
void func1(....){<Cursor1>
// Region 1
}

void func2(....){<Cursor2>
// Region 2
}

void func3(....){<Cursor3>
// Region 3
}

void func4(....){<Cursor4>
// Region 4
}
```

in those functions where the cursors are I would like to select all the code regions with a single action. Unfortunately select to brackets only selects one of the cursors. Is it possible to automate this somehow?

I am fine if it is possible to do it with other editors e.g.Brackets or Sublime Text 3 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the extension [expand_region](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=letrieu.expand-region).  It does what you want nicely.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a way to do it partially even though it is not optimal.

In case anyone can come up with a better solution I will gladly accept it, otherwise I will mark this as the answer after a few days.

Simply use Fold Levels to fold to the function level (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) (numbers will change depending on how nested your functions/namespaces are).

This will likely allow the braces to be consistent 1 or 2 lines depending on your coding style. This way you can select the braces altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I think to do that in VS code is pretty simple i.e. using multi cursor for type, select(copy) and delete(erase) contents simultaneously. Since I use windows I'll show you steps accordingly:

Press the <kbd>ALT</kbd> + mouse pointer for multi cursor feature for all places you need multi cursor then type, select or delete what you want once done to bring back the single cursor mode press <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.